# Working on second tab in java selenium But unable to interact with the elements on the second tab

Tags: java, arrays, selenium-webdriver

I am working on airbnb site I have searched mumbai and then clicked on the respective content which redirects the browser to open the content in a new tab the search is working fine also I am able to shift on the second tab using arraylist, but I am not able to interact with any element on the second tab using java selenium I am getting error a unable tolocate element,the focus is shifted to the second tab but even javascript is not working on the second tab

```
package Practice;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;


public class Airbnbmumbai
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "pathtochromedriver");
        ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();
        ops.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ops);
        driver.get("https://www.airbnb.co.in/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().forward();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // Clicking on trending //
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"f19g2zq0 dir dir-ltr\"]")).click();
        driver.navigate().forward();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // Getting the title of the page on starting of the page //
        System.out.println("Page title is : " + driver.getTitle());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"query\"]")).sendKeys("Mumbai");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"_r1t6ga\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class=\"_1gazwvry notranslate\"])[4]")).click();
        driver.navigate().forward();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/section/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]/div")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"p1kudodg dir dir-ltr\"]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class=\"i98ho2o dir dir-ltr\"])[2]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/button[2]/span")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"t1l18xbv dir dir-ltr\"]")).click();
        driver.navigate().forward();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]")).click();
        System.out.println("Page title is : " + driver.getTitle());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]")).click();
        // Now will work on the second window //
        String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
        // Clicking on see all photos //
        System.out.println("Page title is : " + driver.getTitle());
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //img[@id=\"FMP-target\"]")).click();
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");




    }

}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Is it this line `driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //img[@id=\"FMP-target\"]")).click()` which is throwing `Unable to locate Exception`? Worth checking if the XPATH expression is genuinely correct? I cannot access this site from my location, hence can't check myself. Also(although it shouldn't make difference), I see a leading whitespace in this XPATH expression, correct it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace 
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));

To 
Set<String> tab1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
        int count=tab1.size();
        for(String second:tab1) { 
            driver.switchTo().window(second); 
        }
```